# Reporting in TFS 2013

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, reporting-services, tfs

I am currently working on TFS 2013 and would like to know how to generate custom reports.

Tried google to find out a tutorial but couldn't find anything great. If someone has then please let me know.

Whether SQL Server 2008 R2 Enterprise Reporting Service will be ok for TFS 2013 to generate reports?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

TFS has a few mechanisms for doing reporting:

- **Work Item Queries (WIQ)** - Work Item Queries can be created and saved for reuse.  Work Item Queries are easy to create, and can answer the majority of questions that users have.
- **Excel Reporting** - Work Item Queries can be exported to Excel to provide more advanced capabilities around analyzing the data resulting from the Query.  Various different views of the data along with charts/graphs can be created using standard Excel functionality.  Creating Excel Reports requires some expertise in Excel, but the resulting file can be saved and the data can be automatically refreshed from TFS.
- **SSRS (SQL Server Reporting Services)** - This is the most advanced Reporting option.  SSRS reports require a developer to create, but it provides the flexibility to report and analyze any data stored in TFS in almost any way imaginable.
- **TFS Web Access (TWA)** - TFS Web Access provides some basic charts/graphs that can be viewed in the browser (Burndown, Cumulative Flow, Velocity Chart, etc).  In addition, web-based Charts/Graphs can be generated based on the results of Work Item Queries.  This is less flexible than the Excel option, but also more user-friendly and usable by any TFS user.

The advanced option - SSRS Reports - are just your run-of-the-mill SSRS reports that use the TFS Data Warehouse and/or the TFS Cube as a data source.  You can read a guide about developing custom SSRS reports for TFS here: http://vsarreportguide.codeplex.com/

Comment: Dylan Smith - Thanks for the reply. I will be Ok if I can use excel and do the reporting. Somehow  "Create Report in Excel" option is disabled even for flat list query. If I understand correctly, I need to configure Reporting option in TFS, then TFS will create two DB - Tfs_Warehouse & Tfs_Analysis. To do this I need to have reporting services installed on my system. Please let me know if I have got it right or not?

Comment: I usually just run a Work Item Query and open that in Excel, then create any charts/graphs based off that data in Excel.  So instead of choosing the Create Report in Excel, run a WI Query in VS, then click the Open in Office/Excel button in the toolbar.

Comment: Thanks...my requirement is that every month i need to generate the report from TFS and display capactiy planning(how much time one has spent & others...) This requires that every month the query needs to be editied and then export to excel... I am looking fr something in TFS where one can execute query against that month iteration and give the results....